# adb push Launcher.apk system/app failed

Tags: android, adb, apk, mount

I want to push a Launcher.apk to system/app, but it failed.
(1) No error message,
(2) it looks successful,
(3) but it didn't change anything after I reboot my device.

following command I used:
adb remount
adb push  Launcher.apk  system/app/

but it's weird, 
adb install -r Launcher.apk  ,it works fine!

Is there something I don't notice?,
**how can I push Launcher.apk to system/app/ successfully?**

Answer (score 0):

```
adb remount
adb push Launcher.apk /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/Launcher.apk
adb reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later!
but, why I should chmod 644?

Comment: 644 means only you can change it, everyone else can read it. You can refer this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26645/why-use-chmod-644-instead-of-chmod-u-rw-go-r

Comment: Thank you very much,
I knew why I can't push Launcher.apk into system/app/.
Because there are two files in my stroage:
(1)system/app/launcher.apk
(2)system/app/launcher.odex
when I removed launcher.odex, it works.